# Selenium Python is unable to locate an element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to webdrivers and am experimenting with them.
I'm trying to click a button when opening a webpage and it keeps giving the error of unable to locate element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("html page")

button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
button.click()
```

i have tried id and xpath but i dont know what else to use.
the path for the button is:
/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/button

```
<button id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler" tabindex="0">Run</button>
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to wait until the page is fully loaded?  See the [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Comment: If the suggested wait option doesn't resolve the issue, including some more HTML code for the test page or possibly the URL to your test page (even a similar page) within your question could help with further debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can use implicit wait for wait until the page is fully loaded

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```